# Error : Object.create in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I work with an old JS compiler, so when i try with this instruction:

```
constructor.prototype = Object.create(_super.prototype)
```

i'm getting

> Object.create is not a function

How can i modify this instruction using new or other thing?

Comment: what's your compiler and browser type, version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
constructor.prototype = {__proto__: _super.prototype};
```

or another approach with 'empty' constructor:

```
function Obj(){};
Obj.prototype = _super.prototype;

constructor.prototype = new Obj();
```

Comment: But `__proto__`  will work in the `FF/Chrome`, we are still not quite sure with the OP's browser

Comment: yes, I know that. Therefore, I've added another approach

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest   i tried the first one and it works thank you, but i have the same problem with Object.defineProperty

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create()` is a EMCAScript 5 feature.

You can emulate it via:

```
if (typeof Object.create === 'undefined') {
    Object.create = function (o) { 
        function F() {} 
        F.prototype = o; 
        return new F(); 
    };
}
```

However, there are some subtle differences between native `Object.create()` and this, so this might or might not cause problems down the road.

More [background](https://jaxenter.com/a-modern-approach-to-object-creation-in-javascript-107304.html).